# How to subtract a NumPy array from another one with a condition on the elements of the first one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This question sounds like it may have already been solved, but even though I looked, I couldn't find an answer.

So, I've got a `NumPy` array that contains zeros in some indices:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 0, 0], [7, 8, 0]])
```

And another `NumPy` array, with the same shape, that may or may not contain zeros (it usually doesn't):

```
b = np.array([[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]])
```

I need to subtract `b` from `a` only where `a` is not zero.

So, my result should be:

```
array([[-9, -9, -9],
       [-9, 0, 0],
       [-9, -9, 0]])
```

Notice that because I'm not subtracting when `a` is zero, the zeros stay in place.

First, I tried using a mask:

```
a[a!=0] = -b
```

But the mask, of course, only returns the elements that are not zero and all the information about the indices is lost, so this fails:

```
TypeError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment requires a 0 or 1-dimensional input, input has 2 dimensions.
```

Then, I tried using `np.subtract` with the argument `where`:

```
subtraction = np.subtract(a, b, where=a!=0)
```

But it resulted in this (I assume it's because of the mask created by `where`):

```
array([[-9, -9,                  -9],
       [-9, 2314885530817014877, 3183534901137448992],
       [-9, -9,                  80]])
```

I've also thought of using `np.nonzero` to get the non-zero indices and then iterate over them and subtract the elements, but my arrays can be quite large and can contain either almost all zeros or almost no zeros, so in the latter case, it could become a expensive operation in terms of time.

Is there a simple way to achieve my desired result?

Comment: `np.where(a, a-b, a)`

Comment: Ok, so I assume that `where` works like an `if-else` statement, if `a` happens to be `True` in a particular index (so, when it is not zero, not nan, etc), `where` returns `a-b`, and otherwise it returns `a` that would be zero in this case.

Comment: The `where` condition of `subtract` only works to affect the `out` parameter. When one is not provided you simply get the default "a freshly-allocated array is returned." Which has some random junk inside based on whatever memory block was allocated. You could do `np.subtract(a, b, a, where=(a != 0))` to assign back to `a` instead of getting the values from a random empty array. Or, alternatively, create a new array of zeroes of the correct shape or making a copy of `a`.

Comment: @6659081 - Yes, details [`here`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Comment: Thanks, I had encountered `where` when trying to solve my problem, but didn't understand the docs the first time.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 0, 0], [7, 8, 0]])
b = np.array([[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]])

sub = np.where(a, a-b, a)
print(sub)
```

**Output:**

```
[[-9 -9 -9]
 [-9  0  0]
 [-9 -9  0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a trick for this. we can convert all non-zero values of `a` to 1 and we will multiply it with `b` which will make all values of b to zero at the same index where `a` values are

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 0, 0], [7, 8, 0]])
b = np.array([[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]])

c = a.copy()

# convert all non-zero values to 1
c[c!=0]=1

# match the 0
d = c*b

# now we will subtract d from a
a-d
```

output

```py
array([[-9, -9, -9],
       [-9,  0,  0],
       [-9, -9,  0]])
```

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

As you think first, you can performed what you want with a mask:

```
a[a != 0] = a[a != 0] - b[a != 0]
a
# Output:
array([[-9, -9, -9],
       [-9,  0,  0],
       [-9, -9,  0]])
```